# Python password system with lock after certain number of attempts

Tags: python, time, passwords

So I am trying to create a password system in Python, whereby after a certain number of incorrect attempts, the user will be blocked from accessing it for, say, 5 minutes. I am currently unsure how the values of the variables can be kept after rerunning the same file and then used in this manner. Could someone help me with this, as I am currently still new to Python?

Update:

After experimenting for a while with the code Jonas Wolff provided me I finalised my code to the following:

```
def password(): 
    count = 0 
    currentTime = float(time.time()) 
    passwordList = ["something", "password", "qwerty", "m42?Cd", "no"] 
    passwordNum = random.randint(0, 4) 
    password = passwordList[passwordNum] 
    with open("password.txt", "r") as file:
        check = file.readline()
        initialTime = file.readline()
        if initialTime=="":
            initialTime==0
    if int(check)==1 and (currentTime-float(initialTime))<300:
        print("You are still locked")
        print("Please try again in", int(300-(currentTime-float(initialTime))), "seconds.")
        quit()
    print("The randomised password is No.", passwordNum+1) #Prints a string to let the user know which password was randomly selected
    while count<5:
        inp = input("Enter the Password: ")
        if inp==password:
            print("Access Granted")
            print()
            f = open("password.txt", "w")
            f.write("0\n0")
            f.close()
            select()
        elif (count+1)==5:
            print("You have been locked")
            print("Please try again in 5 minutes")
            f = open("password.txt", "w")
            f.write("1\n")
            f.write(str(currentTime))
            f.close()
            quit()
        else:
            count+=1
            print("Incorrect Password")
            print("You have", 5-count, "tries left.")
            continue
```

Thanks a lot for the help you have provided and the patience with which you answered my questions.

Comment: Show us your code please. [ask]

Comment: Are you looking to store some kind of information in a file between runs of the problem?

Comment: maybe you could use the timeit module

Comment: do you want the attempt to be stored even when program is closed as you previously wrote?

Comment: Yes, I do want the attempt to be stored even after the program has been closed so that if it is rerun after the password was entered incorrectly each time, the user would be unable to enter the password until the 'lock' duration is over. I have tried using pickle to do this but am still unsure how it would work. Would there be easier methods, such as the sessionStorage in JavaScript? Note that I am trying to do this solely in Python (since I think it is possible if I used SQL or similar databases). If it can't be done just let me know. Thanks.

Comment: YourProgram() the code you want to run once succesfull so lets say you have a function inside YourProgram.py thats called starta and you want to run this function when user is succesfull then you write YourProgram.starta() if you want the whole file executed simply move the import to the YourProgram() and replace it.

Comment: as for the float() i'm currently using python 3.6.1 so i will update and see if that is what is causing the trouble :) -  i can see the time module has been changed in 3.7 maybe thats the culprit to sec

Comment: i have now tested it in 3.7 and it seams to work fine may i ask which python your using to run this version and type?

Comment: I am currently using python 3.6.5, so I don't know what's going on either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import YourProgram # this is the program you want to run, if the program runs automaticly when opened then move the import to the part where i wrote YourProgram() and delete the YourPregram() line
import time

pswd = "something"

count = 0

with open("PhysxInit.txt","r") as file:
    file_info = file.readline()
    numa = file_info.count("1")
    count = numa


while True:
    with open("PhysxInit.txt","r") as file:
        file_info = file.readline()
        tima = file.readline()


    inp = input("What is the password:")



    if inp == pswd:

        if tima == "":
            tima = "0"  # this should solve yoúr problem with float convertion however it doesn't make sence that this step should be needed


        if str(file_info[:5]) != "11111" or time.time() > float(tima):
            YourProgram() # this is just meant as the thing you want to do when when granted acces i magined you where blocking acces to a program.
            f = open("PhysxInit.txt", "w")
            f.write("\n")
            f.close()
            break
    else:
        count += 1
        f = open("PhysxInit.txt", "w")
        f.write(("1"*count)+"\n"+str(tima))
        if count == 5:
             f.write(str(time.time()+60*5))
        f.close()

#f = open("PhysxInit.txt", "w")
#f.write("\n")
#f.close()
```

does this work?
just make sure you have a text file called PhysxInit.txt

after running the program, and having guessed wrong a few times my txt file look like this.

```
11111
1536328469.9134998
```

it should look something like mine though the numbers may be diffrent.

To read a specific line as you requested you need to do:

```
with open("PhysxInit.txt", "r") as f:
    for w,i in enumerate(f):
        if w == #the number line you want:
            # i is now the the line you want, this saves memory space if you open a big file
```

Comment: fixed it now, it will read how many time you have already tried

Comment: I have just tried your code but after entering the password it asks for it indefinitely. Is there anything in your code I need to adjust so that it will work with my program (I have a txt file called PhysxInit)?

Comment: remember if you failed to type it in 5 times your locked out for good, since it saves it in the text file.

Comment: on another note it stores the numerber of failed tries as numer of ones in the PhysxInit.txt file you reset thist by manually deleting them, it automaticly deletes them if you within your FIRST indefinitely 5 tries guess correct and it will forget you ever guessed wrong, however do you gues wrong 5 times, then there is no automatical way to go back, as i can understand you want this to happen through a said time that has passed, this can be done if a certain timestamp has passed in which you write "\n" on the first line

Comment: I have edited the code and it seems to work now so that it only locks you out for 5 minutes instead of forever

Comment: After trying a few things, I am still in need of help. The float(tima) cannot convert it to a float and an error appears. How could this be fixed? Also how would you specifiy for the file.readline() to read a specific line?

Comment: the float should work! if you give the error message, maybe i can help, what goes for readline(), i have updated the answer with an solution